# Program crashing when Applying SHA-256/SHA-512 instead of SHA-1 when signing documents with RSA

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

First I generate a Signature and place in the txt_EmpSignature text box and then to sign documents i'm using the following argument in the "Sign" button click event handler:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider MySigner = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
openFileToSign.ShowDialog();
FileStream file_to_sign = new FileStream(openFileToSign.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader reader_to_sign = new BinaryReader(file_to_sign);

byte[] data_to_sign = reader_to_sign.ReadBytes((int)file_to_sign.Length);
MySigner.FromXmlString(txt_EmpSignature.Text);
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] signature_to_sign = MySigner.SignData(data_to_sign,SHA);
UTF8Encoding UTF = new UTF8Encoding();
txt_DocSignature.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(signature_to_sign);
reader_to_sign.Close();
file_to_sign.Close();
```

Then when I replace the "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider" with "SHA256CryptoServiceProvider" I get an unhandled exception that i couldn't specify!
Is there any difference when handling SHA-2 algorthims instead of SHA-1?

#### **EDIT1:**

The Exception happens when I specify the file and click "Open" in the "openFileToSign" Open File Dialogue. And I'm working on "WINDOWS 7"

**EDIT2:**

The Exception message says "Value was invalid"
and the exception happenes in the line:

```
byte[] signature_to_sign = MySigner.SignData(data_to_sign,SHA);
```

Comment: What is the name/content of the exception. Do you have access to the stack trace? And... where do you get it, what line?

Comment: @Skurmedel, i just edited the question to include the message of the general exception as i couldn't specify the exact type.

Comment: What do you mean you "couldn't specify"? Just copy and paste the exception into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as i found the answer finally in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/08/25/using-rsacryptoserviceprovider-for-rsa-sha256-signatures.aspx).
It turned out that ***SHA256CryptoServiceProvider*** is not understood by the ***CryptoConfig***.
Instead, we use ***SHA256Managed*** to generate the hash and then everything will work beautifully.

Comment: Can't vote this up enough.  Every other solution I read involved modifying the machine.config which also didn't resolve the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say if you do not say the exact exception. But note that SHA-2 was not supported in older versions of Windows. It has been added to Windows XP in SP3, and in Windows 2003 Server in a hotfix or something. See [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2010/09/30/sha2-and-windows.aspx).

Comment: I edited my question to note that i'm working on windows 7 :-)

Comment: Thanks - you still haven't told us what the exception is, though.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your are trying to use a 512-bit key. 512-bit keys are too short to use with SHA-256 (there is not enough room for the minimum padding).

Try using a 1024- or 2048-bit key instead.

Comment: I thought about that and i tried to generate the key with different sizes "512, 1024, 2048" and i'm still getting the same result.